# dd works but echo does not for an object passed as a parameter to a function in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I passed an object in a function in laravel. 
I tried to assign the value of a property to a variable. It pops an error.

When I tried to figure out what was going on I tried to dd ()the value it worked.

But when I tried to echo the same it does not.

What am I mising.

On using this,

> location1 and location2 are two objects of the location class.

The function is here:

```
function geodistance($location1,$location2){
    dd($location1->lat);
    $lat1=$location1->lat;
}
```

it prints

> "28.612072"

But when I change the same function to

```
function geodistance($location1,$location2){
    echo($location1->lat);
    $lat1=$location1->lat;
}
```

The output error is:

> Trying to get property 'lat' of non-object

Even the function

```
function geodistance($location1,$location2){
echo $location1->lat;
$lat1=$location1->lat;
}
```

gives the same output

The aim to remind you is to assign the value to a variable like so.

```
function geodistance($location1,$location2){
    $lat1=$location1->lat;
}
```

When I echo $location1 from within the function geodistance() gives out and error which makes sense.

```
function geodistance($location1,$location2){
    echo $location1;
    $lat1=$location1->lat;
```

> Object of class App\MyClasses\city could not be converted to string

When I dd ($location1 from the funciton like so it gives the right result.

```
function geodistance($location1,$location2){
  dd($location1);
  $lat1=$location1->lat;
```

like so:

> city {#13410 ▼
>   +id: 2245
>   +info: "{}"
>   +name: "New Delhi"
>   +lat: "28.612072"
>   +lon: "77.22978"
>   +timezone: null
>   +weightedrating: null
>   +country_id: 1 
>   }

It seems i am missing out something very trivial. :(

Comment: can you provide the code where you call both geodistance() functions

Comment: are you passing array as parameters in function?

Comment: `dd` will dump the variable and terminate the script but `echo` will not terminate, which may mean that `$location1` is an object the first time the method is called but not every time the method is called.

Comment: Have you tried `echo $location1->lat;` ? (no parenthesis) Also consider apokyfos  notes, and the fact that not immediately terminating the script might turn difficult to find your printed value after script termination view rendering.

Comment: @apokryfos: NO the error is being displayed in laravel with the right line number.: Yes. Updated the results.

Comment: @SalmanZafar: It is an element in an array of the objects. 

So there is an array of the type "locations" and the two parameters are 2 elements of the array.

Comment: Have you tried return ?

Comment: @SalmanZafar: no I did not understand what u mean by trying "return"  :(

Comment: Try return $location or return $location->lat;

Comment: @SalmanZafar: it works fine for both.  return $location and the dd of the same gives out the desired object. and return $location->lat and dd of it gives the latitude value correctly. :/

Comment: Now do this.$lat1=$location1->lat:
return $lat1;

Comment: u want me to put a colon sign? I tried that but it pops an error. 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':'

Comment: @NishantSah no colon sign.
semicolon.. $lat1=$location1->lat; return $lat1;

Comment: @NishantSah the line number being correct doesn't mean that what I noted can't still be true

Comment: @SalmanZafar: error "Trying to get property 'lat' of non-object"

Comment: @apokryfos I got u now. You were right. 
The error was that one of the later items was being passed as an object of another class :(

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @salman zafar and @apokryfos, the mistake was that I was passing an array.

When I was doing a dd, after processing the first data the programme was terminated.

The array that was passed was not completely correct. The last data point in my array was not an object of the same class.

So the data ended up being corrupted when using echo. Echo would print one data after another but eventually it would get a wrong input.

The best way to catch these errors (after so much experimenting) is to write the values of the variable in a text file on each iterartion. 
What that does is that it catches the error in your text file and u get to know after how many iterations the programme stopped.

Hope this helps others from making such obviously glaring mistakes which are tough to catch (atleast for me since this was the first of such errors)